# Why is Django's admin detail page making so many queries?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working on a fairly standard Django app and lately I've been tweaking the admin. While the list views load at reasonable rates, the detail and add views take some ~10 seconds to load.

I'm not exactly sure why it is so-- I suspected it had something to do with the database being over queried, and in fact it is. After turning on logging I discovered that the controller is querying for every id in the table:

```
...
[Mon Oct 22 18:32:52 2012] [error] (0.001) SELECT `courses_course`.`id`, `courses_course`.`semester`,
 `courses_course`.`name`, `courses_course`.`credits`, `courses_course`.`description`, `courses_course
`.`history_id`, `courses_course`.`oldpcr_id`, `courses_course`.`primary_alias_id` FROM `courses_cours
e` WHERE `courses_course`.`id` = 2077 ; args=(2077,)
[Mon Oct 22 18:32:52 2012] [error] (0.000) SELECT `courses_course`.`id`, `courses_course`.`semester`,
 `courses_course`.`name`, `courses_course`.`credits`, `courses_course`.`description`, `courses_course
`.`history_id`, `courses_course`.`oldpcr_id`, `courses_course`.`primary_alias_id` FROM `courses_cours
e` WHERE `courses_course`.`id` = 2078 ; args=(2078,)
[Mon Oct 22 18:32:52 2012] [error] (0.001) SELECT `courses_course`.`id`, `courses_course`.`semester`,
 `courses_course`.`name`, `courses_course`.`credits`, `courses_course`.`description`, `courses_course
`.`history_id`, `courses_course`.`oldpcr_id`, `courses_course`.`primary_alias_id` FROM `courses_cours
e` WHERE `courses_course`.`id` = 2079 ; args=(2079,)
...
```

Can somebody explain why this is happening? I can't think of anything at all that might explain it.

Comment: How are you tweaking the admin?

Comment: Nothing significant-- Just adding ModelAdmins to enable search and filtering and the like. I noticed the effect before I got started so likely someone before me is responsible-- but I can't really guess where to even begin looking.

Comment: I think I've seen this behavior before. Reason: I wasn't using select_related on my queries

Comment: So simply setting that to true doesn't quite help, but that's a helpful lead at least.

Comment: What do you mean by setting it to true? select_related is a QuerySet method. Take a look at [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Er, the admin models have a [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) that says whether or not to use them.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. For a minute I forgot this is about the admin

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719662/django-admin-performance-issue. It looks like one of the models is probably in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer here: [Improving Performance of Django ForeignKey Fields in Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108080/improving-performance-of-django-foreignkey-fields-in-admin)

Because Django lists foreign keys as a `select` list, it has to query every one. it looks like several solutions are possible, but the simplest is just to set the field to a [raw_id field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields). (And in fact, doing so fixed my problem.)