# Why does Django admin list_select_related not work in this case?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-admin

I've got a `ModelAdmin` class that includes a foreign key field in its `list_display`. But the admin list page for that model is doing hundreds of queries, one query per row to get the data from the other table instead of a join (`select_related()`).

The Django docs [indicate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) you can add `list_select_related = True` as an attribute to your ModelAdmin to make this go away, but it doesn't seem to work at all for me. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719662/django-admin-performance-issue) seems to give a similar problem, but his resolution is unclear, and it doesn't work in my case.

Here's a cut-down version of my model and model admin:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, unique=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        s = str(self.serial_number)
        if self.label:
            s += ': {0}'.format(self.label)
        return s

class Event(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=True, default='')

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'device')
    list_select_related = True
```

However, adding that `list_selected_related = True` didn't change anything. I still get lots of queries like this instead of an SQL join:

[image: Lots of queries, not a join]

Any ideas why the Django admin seems to be ignoring my list_select_related and doing N queries? I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.3.3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue here is that setting `list_select_related = True` just adds a basic `select_related()` onto the query, but that call does not by default follow ForeignKeys with `null=True`. So the answer is to define the queryset the changelist uses yourself, and specify the FK to follow:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'device')
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(EventAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related('device')
```

Comment: Thanks! The `null=True` on the foreign key was definitely preventing the selected_related doing its thing. I guess if I'd followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) all the way down, I'd have seen that: "Note that, by default, select_related() does not follow foreign keys that have null=True"

Comment: Out of interest, do you know why `list_select_related = True` isn't the default for the Django admin? That would seem to be a much more sensible default. (I can see why by default `select_related()` doesn't follow foreign keys that have null=True, because that could be a performance issue, but I'm wondering about `list_select_related` in other cases.)

Comment: In Django>=1.6 the method is now named `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 10):

[Since Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related), `list_select_related` accepts a boolean, list or tuple with the names of the fields to include in the `select_related()` call.
Hence you can now use:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'device')
    list_select_related = ['device']
```

Comment: +1 While Daniel Roseman's answer provides a good peek into how things work. This answer is the simpler/updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Although `select_related` is generally the way to go, there are time when one requires more control, then overiding the `get_queryset` becomes more applicable, this is a more modern version of Daniel Roseman's answer:

Where `foo` and `bar` are foreign key fields:

```py
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.select_related('foo', 'foo__bar').only('foo__field1', 'foo__bar__field2')
```